# How to send credit card number as Encrypted form in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, encryption

I want to send the registration form details which are having fields like FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Email and Credit Card Number through Post method but my problem is that 
the credit card number should be send as encrypted form. I have no idea about how to encrypt credit card number.